# PHP Sessions problems - Checking Login

Tags: php, forms, function, session, authentication

I'm relatively new to PHP, but I know quite a bit. I am making a login form and I am checking whether they are logged in before they can enter pages and if they are not, then they are redirected to the login page, I am using sessions. Every time that a user logs in or registers it creates a session using:

```
$_SESSION['username'] = '$username';
```

On every page that the user is not allowed to access, I include, checklogin.php - a file I made, with this code:

```
<?php
function checklogin() {
session_start();
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
    return false;
    header('location: login.php');
} else {
    return true;
}
}

checklogin(); //checks login

?>
```

However it doesn't seem to be working as you can access pages when not logged in. Also, there is an if statement:

```
if(!isset($_SESSION['myusername'])){
```

This is used to determine what is shown in the header.

None of this is working, so what am I doing wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Put `session_start();` at the top of your page, not in your function.

Comment: Give me a minute, will try.

Comment: `$_SESSION['username'] !== $_SESSION['myusername']`...

Comment: Header still isn't working and haven't checked the pages that you can't access yet.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to put `session_start()` at the top-side of your PHP file, outside of the checkLogin() function. Session variables need to use the same name, so pick between "username" and "myusername". You also need to swap the order of your statements if the user isn't logged in:

```
 header('location: login.php');
 return false;
```

The `header` call is never happening as the function returns before hand. You also do not need quotes around your variables, e.g. `$_SESSION['username'] = $username;` is correct, assuming `$username` is defined.

Answer (score 0):

```
$_SESSION['username'] = $username;
```

this is the correct syntax use it..